# How OrderBy happens in linq when all the records have the same value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

When orderBy is happened on `datetime` with same value, I am getting different results in different hits from `linq` to `sql` .

Let us  say some 15 records have the same datetime as one of their field
and if pagination is there for those 15 records and per page limit is 10 in my case, say some 10 records came on 1st run for page 1. Then for page 2 I am not getting the remaining 5 records, but some 5 records from the previous 10 records of page 1.

Question:

1. How this orderBy and skip and take functions are working and
2. Why this discrepancy in the result ?

Comment: it depends on the underlying implementation of the querying mechanism that is used by Linq. Linq itself is only an enumerating extension. Can you please specify on to what source your question applies, e.g. MSSQL or in-memory Lists, OrderedLists, etc?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: it is MSSQL @Wicher Visser

Comment: I can not post my code but it happens for all get queries if the orderby column has same value  @Baldrick

Comment: If all values are the same, no ordering is guaranteed. Paging *can't* work because the order can easily change when the same statement is executed again. Therefore, ensure that you use *another* tie-breaker column for ordering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OrderBy clause is resulting different result sets when order column having same data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923593/orderby-clause-is-resulting-different-result-sets-when-order-column-having-same)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not play a role on how the ordering unto the underlying data source is applied. Linq itself is simply an enumerating extension. As per your comment to your question, you are asking how MSSQL applies ordering in a query.

In MSSQL (and most other RDBMS), the ordering on identical values is dependent on the underlying implementation and configuration of the RDBMS. The ordered result for such values can be perceived as random, and can change between identical queries. This does not mean you will see a difference, but you cannot rely on the data to be returned in a specific order.

This has been asked and answered before on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923593/orderby-clause-is-resulting-different-result-sets-when-order-column-having-same).

This is also described in the [community addon comments in this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 1):

No ordering is applied beyond that specified in the ORDER BY clause. If all rows have the same value, they can be returned in whatever order is fastest. That's especially evident when a query is executed in parallel.

This means that you *can't* use paging on results ordered by non-unique values. Each time you make a call the order can change.

In such cases you need to add tie-breaker columns that will ensure unique ordering values, eg the ID of a product `ORDER BY Date, ProductID`