# Skip rows based on booleans

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am looking for an SQL solution, but have an array in PHP like so:

```
$booleans = array(true, false, true, false, false);
```

I know that my SQL query will return exactly the number of booleans in the array.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT name FROM fruits');

// Result after some processing

$result = array('apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'orange', 'mango');
```

How can I apply the booleans to my SQL selection to return only the values which indexes in the array are true. Desired outcome:

```
array('apple', 'pineapple');
```

For optimization I am **not looking for a PHP solution**. I want to implement this in SQL during the selection process.

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: You don't have an `ORDER BY` in your query. How do you know which boolean applies to which row?

Comment: The array is created by a previous selection of the same table, so it should be the same.

Comment: If you've done a previous selection of the table, then why are you opposed to a PHP solution? Hitting the database twice for the same data is always going to be more expensive than filtering the list you already got. Also note "it should be" isn't necessarily true. Without an explicit ORDER BY, you can not guarantee that consistency.

Comment: Can you change the previous selection of Booleans to instead return IDs of the fruit table? i.e. return ([id of apple], -1, [id of pineapple], -1, -1) instead of (true, false, true, false, false). That way you can get your desired result by using `SELECT name FROM fruits WHERE id IN (insert array here)`

Comment: @AlexHowansky I a working on a compiler that parses commands supplied by the user. I have no way of knowing if a second selection will follow but want to keep it as efficient as possible.

Comment: @dc-ddfe That is a great idea and a possible solution! Thank you!

Comment: You _already_ have everything you need. Just filter the existing result set. Making a second query will never be necessary and will never be more efficient.

Comment: Did you try PHP solution? Is it really such a huge performance bottleneck? Why do you want to optimize it?

Comment: @Dharman is this question Clear?  I don't think I am able to connect the dots.  Is there another related table that I'm not seeing?  What is the relationship between the booleans and the fruits???  I think I agree with Alex -- there isn't a lot of certainty/stability in this question ...if I am even understanding it.

Comment: Seemingly relevant: [OrderBy clause is resulting different result sets when order column having same data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17923593/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made efficient by changing the input. Instead of returning (T, F, T, F, F), replace the T's with the ID of the corresponding row and the F's with a number that doesn't appear in the ID table (such as -1).

So assuming the IDs of the fruits are just the counting numbers (1, 2 etc), the returned array from the example would be (1, -1, 3, -1, -1). Following this change in input, the desired result can be obtained with the query `SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE id IN (input array)`.